# Edit legend-value style of AmCharts

Tags: svg, amcharts

This is the code of "graphs" of my AmChart:

```
           "graphs": [{
                "balloonText": "Activos mes actual: [[value]]",
                "title": "Actual",
                "valueField": "activo_actual",
                "fillAlphas": 0,
                "lineColor": "#001ea0",
            }, {
                "balloonText": "Activos mes anterior: [[value]]",
                "title": "Anterior",
                "valueField": "activo_anterior",
                "fillAlphas": 0,
                "lineColor": "#ff0a1b",
            }],
```

As you can see in the red box of this pic:
[image]
The `valueField` `activo_actual`is too long, and it's overflowing the little space that AmCharts has for default in it's template. How can edit that? Is there any option? I tried to edit the class of `amcharts-value-legend`:
[image]
but I just can only add a few style (bold, color, text size) but can't give some margin-left or something like that, it's a svg with the `<text>` tag. Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to edit the SVG directly, you can leverage a couple of properties provided by the `legend` object:

- [`valueWidth`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueWidth) - adjusts the width of the value portion of each legend entry

  [`labelWidth`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#labelWidth) - adjusts the width of the marker title portion of each legend entry

Ex:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  legend: {
    // ...
    valueWidth: /* some value */,
    labelWidth: /* some value */,
    // ...
  }
});
```

Tweaking these should help prevent the text overlap you're seeing.